# How can I host a Discord bot with Replit?

Tags: python, discord, replit

I'm using [Replit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replit) to create a Discord bot in Python.
At first, I used the `keep_alive` method ([Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29) + UptimeRobot):

```
import flask
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return "Now bot online, chill :)"


def run():
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)

def keep_alive():
    server = Thread(target=run)
    server.start()
```

But now, this method doesn't work. It says: "Hmm... We couldn't reach this Repl
Make sure this Repl has a port open and is ready to receive HTTP traffic", but everything is good (it works earlier).

How can I host my bot for free and without Replit deployments? Or how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Since January 1st, 2024, Replit [no longer keeps webservers alive](https://ask.replit.com/t/68506) while the user is not opening the IDE.

You will need to either use *[Deployments](https://docs.replit.com/hosting/deployments/about-deployments)* (paid feature) or use another service altogether.

Comment: Note that questions seeking for recommendations are off-topic for SO.